# Is there anything wrong with calling objc_msgSend directly?

Tags: objective-c

I would of course use the appropriate version (stret or normal) for the circumstance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing necessarily wrong with it. Many of the language bridges do this underneath.

Comment: Just make sure you know *why* you are doing it.

Comment: Rob raises a good point.  Why *do* you want to call it instead of using the ordinary messaging syntax?

Comment: Language bridge, seems faster than nsinvocation

Comment: It's definitely faster than NSInvocation: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/performance-comparisons-of-common-operations.html